# Paste into Excel from Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, paste

I have tried lots of options to paste information copied from other Excel workbook into my new workbook but not success do that (the range is huge - more them 3000 lines).

Please see sample of my script:

```
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $false
$objExcel.displayAlerts = $false
$Src = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')+'\New.xlsx'
$Files = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')+'\Org.xlsx'
$wb1 = $objExcel.workbooks.open($Files)
$Worksheetwb1 = $wb1.WorkSheets.item('Org')
$Worksheetwb1.activate()
$Range = $Worksheetwb1.Range('A1:I1').EntireColumn
$Range.Copy() | Out-Null
$wb3 = $objExcel.workbooks.open($Src)
$Worksheetwb3 = $wb3.WorkSheets.item('Dest')
$Worksheetwb3.activate()
$Worksheetwb3.Columns.item('A:I').clear()
$Range3 = $Worksheetwb3.Range('A1:I1').EntireColumn
$Worksheetwb3.Paste($Range.Value2)
$wb3.close($true)
$wb1.close($true)
$objExcel.Quit()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about exactly what is not working? Do you know how far it gets successfully? If you have a value in `A1` instead of a multi-column range, is the script successful? I deal with PowerShell and Excel frequently but am not able to assist without more detailed information.

Comment: The Paste is not working for me "$Worksheetwb3.Paste($Range.Value2)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer by changing the order of commands the Copy and then immediate after it the paste solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You're pasting into a wrong range. `Worksheet.Paste()` has parameters of destination and link, your code uses destination only, which should be a `Range` belonging to that worksheet. Therefore, the proper line should be this:

```
$Worksheetwb3.Paste($Range3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to Vesper's solution:

```
$Worksheetwb3.Range("A1").Paste() | Out-Null

# Paste special (as values)
$Worksheetwb3.Range("A1").PasteSpecial(-4163) | Out-Null
```